# Docker throws invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  aboutFE:
      build: ./aboutFE
      container_name: aboutFE
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - certbot_certs:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
        - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot:ro
      networks:
        - about
      command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
  certbot:
    image: certbot/dns-digitalocean
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot_certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot
      - ~/.secrets/certbot:/.secrets/certbot
    networks:
      - certbot
    environment:
      - DO_AUTH_TOKEN=token
      - DOMAIN=xxxxxxxxxx
      - WILDCARD_DOMAIN=*.xxxxxxxxxx
    command: certonly --dns-digitalocean --dns-digitalocean-credentials /.secrets/certbot/do.ini --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --email xxxxxxxxxxxx --agree-tos --no-eff-email
networks:
  about:
  certbot:
volumes:
  certbot_certs:
```

and this is my DockerFile

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Can anyone see what i am missing?

Thanks in advance

I am working 10 hour shifts in a kitchen while trying to figure all of this out so my brain is a bit scrambled lately. Other posts do not seem to match my issue

Comment: Change `aboutFE` to lower case.

Comment: i wish you had posted this as a porper answer cause you are right. although david gave a more in depth explanation. Thanks friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `build:` an image, Compose by default generates a name based on the service name.  The error you're seeing is that the generated name doesn't match the standard rules for image names, which don't allow uppercase letters.  The easy answer is to change the service name to not contain those:

```yaml
services:
  about_fe:
  #    ^^^
    build: ./aboutFE
```

Compose can generate names for pretty much everything it creates, including containers, so you don't have to manually specify `container_name:` either.

If you do have some reason to need to manually specify the image name (usually because you plan to `docker-compose push` to a respository somewhere) then specifying both `build:` and `image:` together overrides the generated name for the image that gets built.  You could in principle use this to work around the issue you describe in the question as well.